# Our relation to God and the prophet Muhammad in paradise

Tags: prophet-muhammad, allah, death, jannah

When is the first time that we can see God?
In paradise can we talk to God while seeing him and have an answer from him on the spot, and can we talk to the prophet Muhammad at any time?

Comment: I can say that a person could talk to Allah at that time but can't see when would a person meet Allah in Heaven. 
Let me search

Answer (score 2):

Those Deserving of Paradise will be able to see Allah in Paradise, just the way we can see the moon on a clear night.

> When those deserving of Paradise would enter Paradise, the Blessed and the Exalted would ask: Do you wish Me to give you anything more? They would say: Hast Thou not brightened our faces? Hast Thou not made us enter Paradise and saved us from Fire? He (the narrator) said: He (Allah) would lift the veil, and of things given to them nothing would be dearer to them than the sight of their Lord, the Mighty and the Glorious. He then recited the verse: {For those who do good is the best reward and even more} [Sahih Muslim]

And this hadith:

> [The Messnger] (SAWS) also said: "You will see your Lord with your eyes." [Sahih Bukhari]

And also this hadith:

> Jarir (RAA) said: The Messenger of Allah (SAWS) came out to us on the night of the full moon and said: "On the day of rising you will see your Lord as you see this (moon). You will not be harmed by seeing Him." [Sahih Bukhari]

Secondly, we will also be able to meet not just our Prophet Muhammed (SAWS), but also any other Prophet of Allah (AS). For instance, you may even be able to meet a Prophet of an older ummah, like say, Noah (AS) and have a really long conversation with, like say a hundred years or so, and talk to him about his earthly experiences, insha Allah. Time will not be a constraint there.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. But what about whether God will answer us on the spot?

Comment: Not all muslims will go to Heaven, those with a balance of good deeds which are light won't. You need to change some of your adjectives, like the we with Those Deserving of Paradise, you need to check the last paragraph.

Comment: @James, eventually all Muslims will enter Paradise, except those who commit shirk. I guess the events described in the hadith will happen after that.

Comment: @user2651062, whether God will answer us on the spot: why not? He does hear and respond to each person individually even when millions assemble in one place and invoke Him.